tic tac toe Using minMax algorithm
First of all hello
I am trying to implement a tic tac toe game using the minimax algorithm i tried many ways until i got comfortable with this implementation but I am facing some unlogic moves from the AI move i tried to debug many times i can't reach the unlogic error that gives me sequential moves by the AI move
I am trying to get optimal sol from Ai so that X will not win or Ai wins
import random


class TicTacToe:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize with empty board"""
        self.board = [" ", " ", " ",
                      " ", " ", " ",
                      " ", " ", " "]

    def show(self):
        """Format and print board"""
        print("""
          {} | {} | {}
         -----------
          {} | {} | {}
         -----------
          {} | {} | {}
        """.format(*self.board))

    def clearBoard(self):
        self.board = [" ", " ", " ",
                      " ", " ", " ",
                      " ", " ", " "]

    def whoWon(self):
        if self.checkWin() == "X":
            return "X"
        elif self.checkWin() == "O":
            return "O"
        elif self.gameOver() == True:
            return "Nobody"

    def availableMoves(self):
        """Return empty spaces on the board"""
        moves = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.board)):
            if self.board[i] == " ":
                moves.append(i)
        return moves

    def getMoves(self, player):
        """Get all moves made by a given player"""
        moves = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.board)):
            if self.board[i] == player:
                moves.append(i)
        return moves

    def makeMove(self, position, player):
        """Make a move on the board"""
        if self.board[position] == " ":
            self.board[position] = player
            return True
        elif self.board[position] != " " and player is " ":
            self.board[position] = player
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid Move")
            return False

    def checkWin(self):
        """Return the player that wins the game"""
        combos = ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
                  [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
                  [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6])

        for player in ("X", "O"):
            positions = self.getMoves(player)
            for combo in combos:
                win = True
                for pos in combo:
                    if pos not in positions:
                        win = False
                if win:
                    return player

    def gameOver(self):
        """Return True if X wins, O wins, or draw, else return False"""
        if self.checkWin() != None:
            return True
        for i in self.board:
            if i == " ":
                return False
        return True

    def minimax(self, board=None, depth=None, player=None):
        # scores={"X":1,"O":-1,"Nobody":0}
        # if self.gameOver() or depth == 0:
        #     return scores[self.whoWon()]
        win = self.whoWon()
        if win == "X":
            return 1
        if win == "O":
            return -1
        if self.gameOver() or depth == 0:
            return 0
        if player == "O":
            best = 9999
            for i in self.availableMoves():
                if self.board[i] == " ":
                    self.board[i] = player
                    # self.show()
                    # print(f"best at depth:{depth} and i :{i},and best score:{best}")
                    best = min(best, self.minimax(depth=depth+ 1, player=changePlayer(player)))
                    self.board[i] = " "
            return best
        else:
            best = -9999
            for i in self.availableMoves():
                if self.board[i] == " ":
                    self.board[i] = player
                    best = max(best, self.minimax(depth=depth +1, player=changePlayer(player)))
                    self.board[i] = " "
            return best

        # """
        # Recursively analyze every possible game state and choose
        # the best move location.
        # node - the board
        # depth - how far down the tree to look
        # player - what player to analyze best move for (currently setup up ONLY for "O")
        # if depth is zero, then it's the root node or game is over (no more moves)
        # """
        # return 1
        # pass


def changePlayer(player):
    """Returns the opposite player given any player"""
    if player == "X":
        return "O"
    else:
        return "X"


def make_best_move(board, depth, player):
    bestMove = -1
    bestScore = -9999
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if board.board[i] == " ":
            board.board[i] = player
            moveVal = board.minimax(depth=depth, player="O")
            board.board[i] = " "

            if moveVal > bestScore:
                bestScore = moveVal
                bestMove = i
    print("The value of the best Move is :", bestScore)
    print()
    return bestMove
    # """
    # Controllor function to initialize minimax and keep track of optimal move choices
    # board - what board to calculate best move for
    # depth - how far down the tree to go
    # player - who to calculate best move for (Works ONLY for "O" right now)
    # """


# Actual game
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = TicTacToe()
    game.show()

    while game.gameOver() == False:

        isValid = False
        while not isValid:
            person_move = int(input("You are X: Choose number from 1-9: "))
            # c1 = make_best_move(game,-1,"X")
            # isValid = game.makeMove(c1,"X")
            isValid = game.makeMove(person_move - 1, "X")
        game.show()

        if game.gameOver() == True:
            break

        print("Computer choosing move...")
        ai_move = make_best_move(game, -1, "O")
        print(f"ai move:{ai_move}")
        game.makeMove(ai_move, "O")
        game.show()

print("Game Over. " + game.whoWon() + " Wins")


Please update your question by providing specific case where error occurs and describe what you mean by unlogic move.

The main issues are these:

In make_best_move, the player parameter is ignored. Instead, minimax is called with a player argument set to "O". But in your main loop make_best_move is called with player equal to "O" too, so now make_best_move performs moves for "O" and then still calls minimax for it to play moves for "O". This is wrong. make_best_move should take its player argument into account and decide whether to maximize or minimize, and make sure to pass the opponent to the minimax call.

The main loop passes -1 as value for depth. As minimax adds 1 to the depth at each recursive call, you'll quickly reach the base case of depth == 0, and so you'll most often get 0 as evaluation, which means the best move will most often be the first possible move. Have the main loop pass a value of -5 to make sure depth is not reaching 0 before a forced win is detected after a first move of O that is inferior. For example:
 X . .       X O .
 . . .  =>   . . .
 . . .       . . .

With a depth set to -5 this move of O will be discarded, and a better one is played.


Here is a correction for make_best_move:
def make_best_move(board, depth, player):
    bestMove = -1
    # Decide to minimize or maximize
    bestScore = 9999 if player == "O" else -9999 
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if board.board[i] == " ":
            board.board[i] = player
            # Call changePlayer
            moveVal = board.minimax(depth=depth, player=changePlayer(player))
            board.board[i] = " "
            # Minimize or maximize
            if (moveVal < bestScore) == (player == "O"):
                bestScore = moveVal
                bestMove = i
    print("The value of the best Move is :", bestScore)
    print()
    return bestMove

And in the main loop, provide a different depth argument:
ai_move = make_best_move(game, -5, "O")  # Pass -5 for correct play

